# GCSE Computing: "could not convert string to float"

Tags: python, python-3.6

In this task we are to create a file, edit it with a user input and output said file. The extension to this is creating an average and total for the list and writing/reading the file with this new data. However, I keep on getting this error whenever I run it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "python", line 3, in <module>
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '12 13 14 15 16 17'
```

...even though I thought the list would not be in string value in the first place. Please help! Code below:

```
myFile = open("userInput.txt", "wt")
myList = []
usrInput = float(input("Input numbers: "))
myList.append (usrInput)
myList.append (sum(myList)/len(myList))
for item in myList:
    myFile.write(item+"\n")
myFile = open("userInput.txt","rt")
myRead = myFile.read()
print(myRead)
myFile.close()
```

Comment: Do you understand what `float()` does?

Comment: The title of this question doesn't match the error in your code.

Comment: float() converts a value into a float value, right?

Comment: @AryadevChavali it converts a number to a float number or a string representing a number. If you pass a string of several numbers it can't understand what he's trying to convert. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float

Comment: @ShadowMitia Therefore, what type would be best for a list of numbers? "list"?

Answer (score 0):

```
myFile.write(item+"\n")
```

since `item` is a `float`, you cannot add it to a string.

```
myFile.write("{}\n".format(item))
```

would work better.

Aside, you have to close `myFile` before reopening it for reading

```
myFile.close()  # or file may not be flushed
myFile = open("userInput.txt","rt")
```

Answer (score 0):

`float()` can convert a string representing a number to a floating point number.

E.g: `"3"` is converted to `3.0`

When you pass a string of numbers it can't tell what is a number from another.

E.g: `"3 4 50 200000 3.0E20"`

If you want to convert all numbers in a string, you might want to do something like that:

```
my_numbers = "3 4 5 6"
my_numbers = my_numbers.split()
my_floats = []
for num in my_numbers:
    my_floats.append(float(num))
```

The result is `[3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0]`

More about `float` here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float

More about `split` here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use numpy?

```
import numpy
myFile = numpy.loadtxt("your file", delimiter = " ")
```

Notice that the delimiter is the space.
The numbers must be seaprated first, after that you can use them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this line `float(input("Input numbers: "))`. Here you input is space separated numbers. So you can't convert a numbers separated spaces. You need to split all spaces and then convert. Here is modified code. With this you need some other changes also.

```
myList = []
usrInput = map(float, input("Input numbers: ").split())
myList += usrInput
myList.append (sum(myList)/len(myList))

myFile = open("userInput.txt", "wt")
myFile.write("\n".join(map(str, myList)))

myFile = open("userInput.txt","rt")
myRead = myFile.read()
print(myRead)
myFile.close()
```